# What is a procedure for selecting a type of logistic regression for predicting one of 5 classes based on 3 continuous predictors?

Tags: regression, logistic, model, multinomial-logit

What is a procedure for selecting a type of logistic regression model (e.g., multinomial, one versus rest) for predicting the class of a pixel given its red, green, and blue intensities as in https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/billbasener/pixel-values-from-images-over-haiti?datasetId=1899167 ? A class of a pixel may be an element in the set {Vegetation, Soil, Rooftop, Various Non-Tarp, Blue Tarp}. An intensity is an integer between 0 and 255.

Comment: Is your goal to develop a prediction model that you can apply to new data to classify, or are you trying to understand the relationship between pixel qualities and object classes? If the former, why are you using logistic regression over another multiclass classifier that might perform better?

Comment: Noah, my goal is to develop a prediction model that I can apply to new data to classify. I am interested in comparing the predictive performance of multiple types of models.